# How to Delete/Remove DOCTYPE Declaration from the XML Document?

Tags: java, xml, dom, sax, jaxp

how to remove/delete the DOCTYPE declaration from the XML Document using DOM Parser or SAX Parser in JAVA?

If something you wanted to know is missing. Just mention it in your comments.

thanks

Answer (score 6):

This seems to do what you want :

```
try {
    XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLOutputFactory outFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();

    XMLEventReader input = inFactory.createXMLEventReader(
            new FileInputStream("test.xml"));
    XMLEventReader filtered = inFactory.createFilteredReader(
            input, new DTDFilter());
    XMLEventWriter output = outFactory.createXMLEventWriter(
            System.out);

    output.add(filtered);
    output.flush();
}
catch (XMLStreamException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

static class DTDFilter implements EventFilter
{
    @Override
    public boolean accept(XMLEvent event) {
        return event.getEventType() != XMLStreamConstants.DTD;
    }

}
```

Comment: In these lines, it should "newInstance" instead of "newFactory()"
`code`
XMLInputFactory inFactory = XMLInputFactory.newFactory();
    XMLOutputFactory outFactory = XMLOutputFactory.newFactory();
`code`

anyways the filter is not working :-/

Comment: Well, the javadoc says that "This method has been deprecated to maintain API consistency. All newInstance methods have been replaced with corresponding newFactory methods." So I used newFactory(). The filter worked fine on the random xml file I tried it on... You mean you have an input file for which it outputs a DTD ?

Comment: I am totally new to this API(StAX), I have small doubt.
is it not necessary to instantiate XMLEventFactory ?

Comment: I just want to delete this line from my xml document `code` <!DOCTYPE ~~~filepath~~~ > `code`

Comment: This code does remove the DTD. But the file is reformatted by the XML serializer, which maybe is what you dont like. If you want to just remove the DTD line without any other changes I dont think it can be done using any XML API. You can never really control the way they write their output (as it shouldn't matter anyway).